# Feature request: Can we make it so that a user has to give a reason to downvote a question or answer?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

I am new to the stackexchange community, and have a suggestion to make. Can we set up a system so that to downvote a question or answer, because the purpose of downvoting is not to discourage users, but to weed out spam and answers that do not help. Having a reason or why their question or answer was not helpful will allow the users to contribute productively to the site in the future.

Comment: If this were implemented my comment would be identical every single time.  "The quality of this answer or question is not up to the the community standards and I personally do not find it helpful please see our help center on specific ways to improve your contributions in the future" but I already do that to some degree and I have found people don't actually want to know what's wrong with their contributions because they often believe it's a problem with the community doing something and cannot accept that their contributions quality is extremely poor.

Comment: Besides a downvote already indicates the contribution was not found to be unhelpful

Comment: @Ramhound You have one too many negatives there...

Comment: What?  Please explain

Comment: Quite the opposite; we are encouraged _not_ to explain downvotes anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, the purpose of downvoting is not to discourage users. Every downvote has its reason, and I don't think the downvoter should be forced to spend extra time to explain why they gave the downvote. If they wish to do that, they can post it in the comments.

I do agree that it can sometimes be confusing for new users when they receive downvotes for a post that they thought was excellent according to their own standards. This problem has already been solved to a certain extent [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). I just don't think it should be something mandatory.

Comment: @AnthonyPham - For those that have had people, vote our contributions serially downvoted, because they left a comment explaining our own vote to their contribution.  Would say it's actually, fortunate, that comments are not required to issue downvotes.